# Django - Country -> State-> City Dropdown list

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, state, country, city

I have been trying to create a 3 column drop-down list as Country, State, City.

The list of state will be shown based on which country is selected. and the same thing happens to city depends on which State is selected.

My database is as follow. If a country is selected, then states will show depending on country. Same thing happens to City

A member will select his country,state, and city from an already existed Country, State, City databases

```
from django.db import models


class Member(models.Model):

       residing_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       residing_state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       residing_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Country(models.Model):

         country= models.CharField(max_length=20)

class State(models.Model):

         state=models.CharField(max_length=20)
         country = models.ForeignKey(Country)       

class City(models.Model):

        city=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        state=models.ForeignKey(State)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try also without ajax call:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Demo by kishan Radadiya</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Countries
        var country_arr = new Array("Select Country","AUSTRALIA","INDIA","NEW ZEALAND","USA","UAE","MAURITIUS");

        $.each(country_arr, function (i, item) {
            $('#country').append($('<option>', {
                value: i,
                text : item,
            }, '</option>' ));
        });

        // States
        var s_a = new Array();
        s_a[0]="Select State";
        s_a[1]="Select State|QUEENSLAND|VICTORIA";
        s_a[2]="Select State|ANDHRAPRADESH|KARNATAKA|TAMILNADU|DELHI|GOA|W-BENGAL|GUJARAT|MADHYAPRADESH|MAHARASHTRA|RAJASTHAN";
        s_a[3]="Select State|AUCKLAND";
        s_a[4]="Select State|NEWJERSEY|ILLINOIS";
        s_a[5]="Select State|DUBAI";
        s_a[6]="Select State|MAURITIUS";

        // Cities
        var c_a = new Array();
        c_a['QUEENSLAND']="BRISBANE";
        c_a['VICTORIA']="MELBOURNE";
        c_a['ANDHRAPRADESH']="HYDERABAD";
        c_a['KARNATAKA']="BANGLORE";
        c_a['TAMILNADU']="CHENNAI";
        c_a['DELHI']="DELHI";
        c_a['GOA']="GOA";
        c_a['W-BENGAL']="KOLKATA";
        c_a['GUJARAT']="AHMEDABAD1|AHMEDABAD2|AHMEDABAD3|BARODA|BHAVNAGAR|MEHSANA|RAJKOT|SURAT|UNA";
        c_a['MADHYAPRADESH']="INDORE";
        c_a['MAHARASHTRA']="MUMBAI|PUNE";
        c_a['RAJASTHAN']="ABU";
        c_a['AUCKLAND']="AUCKLAND";
        c_a['NEWJERSEY']="EDISON";
        c_a['ILLINOIS']="CHICAGO";
        c_a['MAURITIUS']="MAURITIUS";
        c_a['DUBAI']="DUBAI";


        $('#country').change(function(){
            var c = $(this).val();
            var state_arr = s_a[c].split("|");
            $('#state').empty();
            $('#city').empty();
            if(c==0){
                $('#state').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select State',
                }, '</option>'));
            }else {
                $.each(state_arr, function (i, item_state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>', {
                        value: item_state,
                        text: item_state,
                    }, '</option>'));
                });
            }
            $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                value: '0',
                text: 'Select City',
            }, '</option>'));
        });

        $('#state').change(function(){
            var s = $(this).val();
            if(s=='Select State'){
                $('#city').empty();
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select City',
                }, '</option>'));
            }
            var city_arr = c_a[s].split("|");
            $('#city').empty();

            $.each(city_arr, function (j, item_city) {
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: item_city,
                    text: item_city,
                }, '</option>'));
            });


        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="country" id="country"></select> <br>
<select name="state" id="state"></select> <br>
<select name="city" id="city"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working as expected. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very easy solution for anyone looking to implement a quick chained dropdown for django (or any website) for country --> state/province --> city, that does not require you to maintain a db.

https://geodata.solutions/

html

```
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                </select>
                <select name="state" class="states" id="stateId">
                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                </select>
                <select name="city" class="cities" id="cityId">
                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

scripts

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//geodata.solutions/includes/countrystatecity.js"></script>
```

its as simple as that.

if you are already loading jquery.min.js for ajax, no need to load it again.  Just load the countrystatecity.js.

Comment: is this paid? will it be available forever

Comment: I like this solution however the last blog post posted (2017) said "I've made the decision to, at least for now, open up the API to anyone who wants to use it without authentication." Not very reassuring...

Comment: The easiest solution ever I got

Answer (score 1):

Ive implemented the same thing successfully using this: http://elo80ka.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/jquery-plugin-chained-select-lists/

EDIT:
I dont have the code at hand, but adapting from the tutorial, first you create a views that returns the appropriate JSON:

```
def filter (request, model_class, field_name):
    try:
        kwargs = {smart_str(field_name): request.GET['q']}
    except KeyError:
        raise Http404
    qs = model_class.objects.filter(**kwargs).values('pk', 'name')
    response = HttpResponse(
        content=dumps(list(qs)),
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
    return response
```

EDIT 2:
For the given schema, you would only need to change the urls.

In your urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^locations/filter/state-by-country/$', 'filter', {'model_class': State, 'field_name': 'country'},  name='state_filter')
    url(r'^locations/filter/city-by-state/$', 'filter', {'model_class': City, 'field_name': 'state'},  name='city_filter')
    ...
)
```

In your template, you would add the following (or you could create js files and add it to the form media, which is a better option):

```
$(function() {
  $('#id_state').chainedSelect({
    parent: '#id_country',
    url: 'locations/filter/find-by-country',
    value: 'id',
    label: 'name'
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#id_city').chainedSelect({
    parent: '#id_state',
    url: 'locations/filter/find-by-state',
    value: 'id',
    label: 'name'
  });
});
```

If you could describe your table schema a little, i could help better.

Comment: class Country(models.Model):

     country= models.CharField(max_length=20)

class State(models.Model):

     state=models.CharField(max_length=20)
     country = models.ForeignKey(Country)       

class City(models.Model):

    city=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state=models.ForeignKey(State)

Comment: I have posted my db schema. I try to keep it simple

Comment: Check Edit 2. I prefer this over the previous mentioned app because its very simple to implement, and once you get familiar with it, you can use it anywhere in your application

Comment: What is URL above should be? I have /mysite/country

Comment: from django.db import models


class Member(models.Model):

       residing_country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       residing_state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       residing_city = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Country(models.Model):

         country= models.CharField(max_length=20)
 
class State(models.Model):

         state=models.CharField(max_length=20)
         country = models.ForeignKey(Country)  

class City(models.Model):

        city=models.CharField(max_length=20)
        state=models.ForeignKey(State)

Comment: The urls listed, are only the urls for the ajax function calls. You will need to append your remaining urlspatterns.

Comment: Can you help me code this part as it is so urgent. I can pay you

Comment: Do you use msn or skype, We can discuss the solution

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with http://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects. This will mean you need to plug all your country/state/city data into the DB which might not be ideal, but it's an idea.